# Companies House(UK) get request, axios

Tags: vue.js, axios

I want to access data from [Companies House](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/index/gettingStarted.html)

- I have an account
- I createad an app
- I get an API key
- On JavaScript domains I have my URL.

When I try to do a request I get a CORS ERROR, and I am not sure why.

```
  axios
    .get(this.$companiesHouseUrl, {
      params: {
        q: this.search_for_company
      },
      crossDomain: true,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(this.$companiesHouseKey + ":")
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Response:", response);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log("Error:", e);
    });
```

On there forum I found this [article](https://forum.aws.chdev.org/t/access-control-allow-origin-using-get-search-companies-api/2058), but still..

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/?q=as'
> from origin 'http://URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Comment: Likely the API isn't meant to be queried from a browser, but is designed as a server-to-server API.

Comment: I don't think that's the case , I updated my question with an article from there forum.

Comment: You can check https://httptoolkit.tech/will-it-cors/… If the API doesn't set appropriate CORS headers (which I don't know whether it's supposed to, but apparently it doesn't), you probably can't use it from a browser.

Comment: Nice website, right now I am on local, but I tested with a URL from live and seems to work from there.

Comment: @Beusebiu You likely still want to make this server-side, as you're exposing your API key to the internet if you do it on the client.

Answer (score 0):

I have just spent the last few hours going around in circles with this problem for axios. I tried multiple suggestions and fixes and could not get anything to work.
I was trying to make a get call to
https://api.company-information.service.gov.uk/search/companies
I supplied the credentials and kept getting a
error: 'Invalid Authorization', type: 'ch:service'

#### How I fixed this

When I set up my account and created my first app I set it in test mode as you would expect because I was testing. In their paper work they say that in test mode you goto their 'sandbox' version. There is no ref to a sandbox endpoint and so I, like a lot of people just presumed that you call the above address and supply your credentials. THIS DOES NOT WORK. Either there is a special url for the sandbox or some other magic??.
However the fix was as simple as creating a new app and setting the enviroment to '**LIVE**' mode. You will then be able to make requests and get data back!
I hope this helps others who are equally frustrated trying to get it to work.
The actual axios code I used that worked and I know axios has built in support but when I was trying a hundred different ways! the one below is the one that worked for me:

```
try {
const url = 'https://api.company-information.service.gov.uk/search  /companies?q='+value;
const response = await axios.get(url, {
headers: {
  Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(YOUR KEY + ":")
 }
});
if ('data' in response) {
if ('error' in response.data) {
// error
console.log(response.data.error.error);
return false;
} else if ('items' in response.data) {
// list of found companies
return response.data.items;
}
}
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```